# Changing the response character of the globbing operator ( '**' )

Tags: wildcards, output

I ran a globbing operator

```
**
```

in a directory listing

```
ls -d "$PWD/"**/
```

but I noted that after pressing return… and waiting… and waiting… it regurgitated its answer at once, after generating thousands of lines.

Can the output be made to generate line at a time instead of glob at a time? I'm wondering if that's a globbing setting, or an OS setting, or a profile setting, too.

(Interestingly, the question crosses a line between what's presented on the outside—the computer monitor—and the computer's internal processing.

The question can be thought of as repositioning my *observer* from the outside of the monitor to a place somewhere on the inside the computer's operational spaces, in a place I can't go, my *observer* cannot go, but which it paradoxically *CAN* go and has just gone there, only… it's in a non-physical space, so we can never be sure of that space, or how that space behaves evidentially.

I'll ask another question in a different space about whether there are other shells that open up our ability to see into those spaces inside the functioning of the computer through the use of those different shells, but I won't delve in any further here since that's outside the scope of this question.)

Answer (score 2):

The point of globs also called filename generation is to generate a (sorted) list of file paths that match the pattern to then pass to some command.

So of course, that list needs to be built first before passing to a command, as the list is passed as a whole as an argument of the `execve()` system call.

You don't have to pass the glob in the arguments of a command, you can also assign the result to an array like in:

```
files=( **/*.txt )
```

Or use in a `for` loop:

```
for file in **/*.txt; do...
```

But there again, the list is built first, sorted, then processed.

If all you want to do is print those files though, what you could if using the zsh shell (where `**/` initially come from in 1992), is to get the shell to `print` it as part of a glob qualifier. Like with:

```
**/*(N^e['print -r -- $REPLY'])
```

Or using a helper function and the `+funcname` qualifier instead of `e[code]`:

```
p() { print -r -- $REPLY; false; }
```

Then:

```
**/*(N+p)
```

Or after `set -o globstarshort`:

```
**(N+p)
```

Or:

```
**(/N+p)
```

For files of type *directory*¹ only.

Beware the list won't be sorted.

Of course, you could use `ls -ld --` in place of `print -r --` but while `print` is a built-in, `ls` is not, and running one `ls` each in a new process for each file would end up being costly.

If you do need to get more information from the files, you'd be better of using zsh's `stat` builtin (`zmodload zsh/stat` first to load it).

---

<sup>¹ here using the `/` glob qualifier. Beware that if you do `**/`, you'll also get symlinks to directories, and a `/` appended to all of them.</sup>

Comment: Respectfully, won't these solutions be prone to the "all at once" nature of globbing that the OP was lamenting?

Comment: @bxm, no the point is to hook code into the globbing process by using the `e`valuate or `+func` qualifiers. The globs themselves expand to nothing as those code/functions return false.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for `find` rather than `ls` and globbing.

```
find "${PWD}" -type d
```

I'm not even going to touch the techno/philosophical postamble.

Comment: TY. What is it about ***find***, though, that seems to make it harder to wrap my head around its use? This may need to be its own thread, instead of hijacking my own thread away from myself. :-P